# How to retain `docker secret`s after restarting a single node swarm without values stored in plain text on file system?

Tags: docker, secret-management

I am trying to learn `docker secret`.  I will use Docker Swarm and only have a maximum of 1 node in the cluster.  I ran these commands:

```
docker swarm init;
printf "test123" | docker secret create db_password -
docker swarm leave -f;
docker swarm init;
docker secret ls;
```

I see this result:

```
ID        NAME      DRIVER    CREATED   UPDATED
```

This means the secrets were lost after restarting docker swarm.

Is there a way to make the secrets persist after restarting docker swarm in a 1 node cluster?  If I have to mount files with these secrets from the host system, the files can not have values visible in plain text.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in docker?